# My Phone recorder service keep crashing

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've the below code in my app for calls recording, but it keep crashes once the 'service' is called!

The `BroadcastReceiver` for detecting the call, and starting the `AudioService` is:

```
class PhoneStateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
        val incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)

        when(state){
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing $incomingNumber", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "On Call $incomingNumber", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            context.startService(Intent(context, AudioService::class.java))
                            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE -> {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        context.stopService(Intent(context, AudioService::class.java))
                         }
        }
    }
}
```

The `AudioService` that is used for recording the call, but keep crashing:

```
class AudioService : Service(), MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

    lateinit var context: Context
    private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    //setting maximum file size to be recorded
    private val Audio_MAX_FILE_SIZE: Long = 1000000//1Mb

    private var mOutputFile: File? = null
    private var mStartTime: Long = 0

    private val outputFile: File
        get() {
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS", Locale.US)
            return File(context.filesDir, //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                  //  .absolutePath.toString()
                    "RECORDING_"  // "/Voice Recorder/RECORDING_"
                    + dateFormat.format(Date())
                    + ".m4a")
        }

    override fun onInfo(mr: MediaRecorder?, what: Int, extra: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
            stopRecording(true)
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        context = this
      //  Toast.makeText(context,"created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Toast.makeText(context,"started recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mRecorder!!.setOnInfoListener(this)

        mRecorder!!.apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            setMaxFileSize(Audio_MAX_FILE_SIZE)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)

            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC)
            setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000)

            setAudioSamplingRate(16000)
        }
        mOutputFile = outputFile
        mOutputFile!!.parentFile.mkdirs()
        mRecorder!!.setOutputFile(mOutputFile!!.absolutePath)

        try {
            mRecorder!!.apply {
                prepare()
                start()
            }

            mStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    private fun stopRecording(saveFile: Boolean) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"stopped recording ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        mRecorder!!.apply {
            stop()
            release()
        }
        mRecorder = null
        mStartTime = 0
        if (!saveFile && mOutputFile != null) {
            mOutputFile!!.delete()
        }
        // to stop the service by itself
        stopSelf()

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopRecording(true)
    }
}
```

In the `AndroidManifest` I added both as below:

```
    <receiver android:name=".broadcasts.PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Services.AudioService" />
```

I already granted the required runtime permission of `android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` in the MainActivity

**UPDATE**

I got this error in the debugger:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed

So, referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846797/2441637) I added the runtime permission of `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` but now getting another error, that is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.

Comment: Can you please post the crash log?

Comment: Please use a debugger (included in android studio) to get the logs of the crash. Look for the error log specifically. It will give you a hint as to why the app is crashing with the specific error and location. If you still can't fix it, you can ask here with the specific error you are facing.

Comment: @XXZ it gives `java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed`

Comment: @Yashovardhan it gives `java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason is due to changes in Android O API. regarding Foreground services, and notifying user about Media recording.

My `Manifest` is:

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcasts.PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".Services.AudioService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

My `Broadcast Receiver` is:

```
class PhoneStateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)
        val record_calls = prefs!!.getBoolean("recordCalls", false)
        val service = Intent(context, AudioService::class.java)

        val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
        val incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)

        when(state){
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING -> {
                      //      Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing $incomingNumber", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
               // Toast.makeText(context, "IS_SERVICE_RUNNING $IS_SERVICE_RUNNING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            if (record_calls) {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    context.startForegroundService(service)
                                } else context.startService(service)
                                IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = true
                                }
            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE -> if (IS_SERVICE_RUNNING) context.stopService(service)
            else -> Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

My `Service` is:

```
var IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = false

class AudioService : Service(), MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

    lateinit var context: Context
    private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    //setting maximum file size to be recorded
    private val Audio_MAX_FILE_SIZE: Long = 1000000//1Mb

    private var mOutputFile: File? = null
    private var mStartTime: Long = 0

    private val outputFile: File
        get() {
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS", Locale.US)
            return File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), //  Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, //    context.filesDir, //
                    //  .absolutePath.toString()
                    "call_"  // "/Voice Recorder/RECORDING_"
                            + dateFormat.format(Date())
                            + ".m4a")
        }

    override fun onInfo(mr: MediaRecorder?, what: Int, extra: Int) {
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
             stopRecording(true)
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Toast.makeText(context,"started recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                val intent = Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
    val nManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    val notification = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Notification.Builder(context, NotificationService.CHANNEL_ID)
            } else {
                Notification.Builder(context)
            }.apply {
                setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)

           setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                setAutoCancel(true)

         setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.recording_title))
                setStyle(Notification.BigTextStyle()                          .bigText(resources.getString(R.string.recording_body)))

          setContentText(resources.getString(R.string.recording_body))
            }.build()


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        startForeground(1, notification);
    } else {
        nManager.notify(1, notification)
    }

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            // reset()
        }
        mRecorder!!.setOnInfoListener(this)

        mOutputFile = outputFile
        mOutputFile!!.parentFile.mkdirs()

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mRecorder!!.apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            //  setMaxFileSize(Audio_MAX_FILE_SIZE)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
            // setOutputFile(mFileName)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC)
            setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000)
            setAudioSamplingRate(16000)
            setOutputFile(mOutputFile!!.absolutePath)
        }

        try {
            mRecorder!!.prepare()
            mRecorder!!.start()
        } catch (ise: IllegalStateException) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error 1 $ise ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (ioe: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error 2 $ioe ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    private fun stopRecording(saveFile: Boolean) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"stopped recording ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        mRecorder!!.apply {
            stop()
            reset()
            release()
        }
        mRecorder = null
        mStartTime = 0
        if (!saveFile && mOutputFile != null) {
            mOutputFile!!.delete()
        }
        // to stop the service by itself
        stopSelf()

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
      //  Toast.makeText(context,"service destroyed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        stopRecording(true)
    }
}
```

My `NotificationUtility` is:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
class NotificationUtils(base: Context) : ContextWrapper(base) {

    val nManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    init {
        createChannels()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createChannels() {
        val myChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT).apply {
            enableLights(true)
            enableVibration(true)
            lightColor = Color.GREEN
            lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        }

        nManager.createNotificationChannel(myChannel)
    }

    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "my.CHANNEL_ID"
        const val CHANNEL_NAME = "my.Notification"
    }
}
```

And for runtime permissions,I created `Context Extensions`:

```
fun Context.toast(message: CharSequence) =
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

fun Context.arePermissionsGranted(permissions: Array<String>): Boolean {
    permissions.forEach { it ->
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, it) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return false
    }
    return true
}

    fun Context.isPermissionGranted(permission: String) =
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    fun Context.batchRequestPermissions(permissions: Array<String>, requestId: Int) =
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this as Activity, permissions, requestId)

    fun Context.requestPermission(permission: String, requestId: Int) =
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this as Activity, arrayOf(permission), requestId)
```

In the `MainActivity` I've:

```
val CALL_PERMISSIONS =
        arrayOf(READ_PHONE_STATE, RECORD_AUDIO, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
const val CALL_RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL = 10

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)  NotificationUtils(this)

val self = this as Context

        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
            setTitle(R.string.permissions_required)
            setIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_all_black_24dp)
            setMessage(R.string.grant_permissions_required)

            setPositiveButton("Confirm", { dialog, i ->
                self.batchRequestPermissions(CALL_PERMISSIONS, CALL_RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL)
            })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following permission needs to be added:

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"`

In addition, it is a "dangerous" permission so it must be granted directly by the user:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Thanks, I got another error, and updated my question.

Comment: Which line is "java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed" happening on?

Comment: `       try {
            mRecorder!!.apply {
                prepare()
                start()
            }`

Comment: java.io.IOException: No valid output file

Comment: yes, it is there: `mRecorder!!.setOutputFile(mOutputFile!!.absolutePath)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170176/discussion-between-xxz-and-hasan-a-yousef).